View is not updated after modelContext.delete(item)
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ItemListView: View {
    @Bindable var luggage: Luggage
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @State private var selectedItem: Item?
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(luggage.items) { item in
                ItemListRow(item: item)
                    .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: true) {
                        Button {
                           modelContext.delete(item)
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "trash")
                        }
                        .tint(.red)
                        
                        Button {
                            selectedItem = item
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "pencil")
                        }
                        .tint(.orange)
                    }
            }

When I do a swipe action to delete my item in a list, SwiftUI is not updating the list. It is deleted when I force quit the app and relaunch it...

Note, there is no need for @Bindable, just var luggage: Luggage should be enough.

Assuming Luggage is a @Model class returned from a SwiftData query,
try replacing modelContext.delete(item) with
if let index = luggage.items.firstIndex(of: item) { luggage.items.remove(at: index) }

Great! your last comment is fixing it! but why? :,)

Because @Model class conforms to observable, so the system does all this for you.
That is, the app uses the autosave feature, SwiftData automatically saves the changes. No need to call the model context in this case.

Assuming Luggage is a @Model class returned from a SwiftData query,
try replacing modelContext.delete(item) with
  if let index = luggage.items.firstIndex(of: item) {
      luggage.items.remove(at: index)
  }

Since @Model class conforms to observable, the app/system will use its autosave feature,
and SwiftData automatically saves the changes for you.
No need to call the model context in this particular case.

@Sebbie_O You also needs to actually delete the object. This solution only deletes the relationship between the luggage and the item object.

@JoakimDanielson, how would you do that? It is strange that ModelContext.delete(item) does not work… it is used in every tutorial..

It will work fine if you do it together with the solution above.

I do not see how you would work with them together?

You need another @Query for the Item model type for it to refresh when the items change, and filter it to be only the items in a specific luggage, e.g. something like:
@Query private var items: [Item]

init(luggage: Luggage) {
    
    let id = luggage.persistentModelID
    let predicate = #Predicate<Item> { item in
        item.luggage?.persistentModelID == id
    }
    
    _items = Query(filter: predicate, sort: [SortDescriptor(\.title)] )
}

